# ¿Cuál es el origen de "sablazo"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, historia

[**Sablazo**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WtWS5k7) aparece en el DLE como

> 3. m. coloq. **Acto de sacar dinero a alguien pidiéndoselo, por lo general, con habilidad o insistencia y sin intención de devolverlo.**

Y con significados relacionados, [**sablear**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WtdxvSI)

> De *sable*<sup>1</sup> y *-ear*.
>   1. tr. coloq. **Sacar dinero a alguien dándole sablazos, esto es, con petición hábil o insistente y sin intención de devolverlo.** U. t. c. intr.

y [**sablista**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WthGZtp)

> De *sable*<sup>1</sup> e *-ista.*
>   1. adj. coloq. **Que tiene por hábito sablear.** U. m. c. s.

y [**sable**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WtYY25L)

> Del fr. *sabre*, este del al. ant. *sabel*, y este del húngaro *szablya*.
>   1. m. Arma blanca semejante a la espada, pero algo corva y por lo común de un solo corte.
>   3. m. coloq. **Habilidad para sacar dinero a otro o vivir a su costa.**

Indagando en el NTLLE he encontrado que **sablazo** se recoge desde 1817, pero únicamente con la acepción de *golpe dado con un sable*, y no es hasta **1889** cuando el DRAE recoge la acepción de *"Acto de sacar dinero a uno, o de comer, vivir o divertirse a su costa*". *Sablista* figura en esa misma edición, mientras que *sablear* y *sable* son posteriores.

En el [**CORDE**](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) he encontrado una referencia anterior (énfasis mío):

> ... le administraba un modesto **sablazo, ó en otros términos, le pedía un duro**. (Carlos Coello, *Cuentos inverosímiles*, 1872-1878)

Este texto parece ser el primero en el que se recoge este uso de *sablazo*, pero al mismo tiempo se explica su significado, lo que sugiere que no estaba muy extendido.

Pero ¿cuál es la relación entre el **golpe dado con un sable** y el **arte de sacar dinero a uno**?  Dado que las definiciones mencionan *arte*, *habilidad*, etc. para obtener el dinero, no parece que la relación sea con amenazas enarbolando un sable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personalmente, y esto es elucubración mía, siempre me he imaginado la relación así: un *sablazo* sería un golpe dado con un sable al bolso, monedero, faltriquera, etc. con el objetivo de rasgarla para que se caiga el dinero contenido en ella, o incluso para que se desprenda de la ropa del portador, sin que este se dé cuenta.

El texto que mencionas como su primer uso debe de estar cerca de sus inicios como expresión, a tenor del siguiente ejemplo del CORDE:

> *Cadenas es un hombre práctico. En su casa hay un gran libro exclusivamente dedicado á lo que allí se llama el sablazo de los amigos. Acaso el lector que lleve muchos años de ausencia de España, ó el americano que lea este libro, ignorarán lo que es un sablazo en la tierra de los hidalgos y caballeros. Un sablazo es la petición del dinero que no se devuelve.*
>
> Eusebio Blasco, "Mis Contemporáneos", 1886 (España).

Otra explicación que se me ocurre es la asimilación del dinero como la sangre vital necesaria para que una persona viva. Del mismo modo que un sablazo literal te saca la sangre del cuerpo, uno figurado te saca el dinero. Nótese como el texto habla del "sablazo de los amigos": un enemigo te atacará con sablazos literales, mientras que los amigos usan el sablazo figurado, que no te mata pero te deja seco (de dinero).

O puede que directamente haga referencia a los asesinatos por sablazos cometidos para robar el dinero de la víctima: los figurados te quitan el dinero igualmente pero no la vida. O a los robos de dinero que usaban el sable como medio de intimidación.

No encuentro referencias exactas, pero tampoco se me hace raro el uso de *sablazo* en este sentido. El uso literal de *sablazo* estaba muy extendido hacia mediados del siglo XIX, lo que hace a esta voz propensa a su uso figurado. Valga el siguiente ejemplo extraído de la hemeroteca de la BNE:

> Hay palabras afortunadas que difunde el vulgo, y que luego toman carta de naturaleza en el Diccionario que fija, limpia y da esplendor. Esto ha ocurrido con la palabra cursi, y esto ocurrirá con la de sablazo.
>       —¿Qué es un sablazo?
>       —Amigos mios, dice uno, ya estoy armado; acabo de dar un sablazo de 1,000 rs. á Fulano.
>       Esto significa que los 1,000 rs. no serán nunca devueltos al desgraciado donante.
>       Haceis el amor á una bella dama, y esta os escribe que os va á dar una gran prueba de confianza, que necesita pagar una cuenta y «nadie como tú, Mengano, á quien tanto quiero, puede sacarme del apuro.» Sablazo inminente.
>       El amigo que temprano os despierta en la cama con la noticia de un compromiso pecuniario, el que os para en la calle y os pregunta á boca de jarro, «!está V. ahora en fondos?» el que en el rincón de un salón os cuenta en reserva pérdidas inesperadas: todos estos llevan levantado un sable invisible.
>
> **[La Época (Madrid)](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000356618&page=4&search=sablazo%20dinero&lang=es)**. 8/3/1877, n.º 8.883, página 4.

Viendo esto me atrevería a fijar la creación del uso figurado de *sablazo* en esa década de 1870.

Answer (score 5):

> **Dar**/pegar/ser **un sablazo**
>
> Abusar de la generosidad de alguien pidiéndole dinero. *Luis no tiene problemas económicos. Cuando se le acaba el dinero, se dedica a dar sablazos a los amigos.* A veces se emplea la expresión para dar a entender que algo ha resultado excesivamente caro: *Hemos ido a ese restaurante francés y por cuatro tonterías que hemos comido nos han dado un sablazo impresionante.* El *sablazo* es, en su primera acepción, el golpe dado con el sable. **Figuradamente, quien recibe tales sorpresas queda igual de herido que si le hubieran dado un sablazo de verdad.** Existe, con el mismo significado que la locución, el verbo *sablear*.
>
> - [*Diccionario de Dichos y Frases Hechas*](http://www.esacademic.com/dic.nsf/sp_sp_dichos_refranes/505/pegar), Alberto Buitrago

La lógica parece análogo a la de los sinónimos [*pechazo*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SGLvk4H) / [*pechada*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SFy6ADg%7CSFzlOFN) (lit. un *golpe* dado con el pecho) que en algunos países de América<sup>1</sup> tiene la misma significación figurativa que *sablazo*.

También hay:

| Palabra | Región | Etimología |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [*fajazo*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HVEwrHz) | Puerto Rico | golpe con una faja > "sablazo" |
| [*mangazo*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OC4Kaqc) | Uruguay | golpe con mango > "sablazo" |
| [*banderillazo*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4xHNILo) | Colombia y Venezuela | golpe con banderilla > "sablazo" |
| [*sableo*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WteL9lT), [*sableada*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Wtbz6ES) | México | sablazo > sablear > sableo, sableada |

---

<sup>**1.** Específicamente [Argentina, Uruguay y Paraguay](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pechazo). Notablemente son los paises en cuales ([como nota pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28052/18348)), *sablazo* no lleva su significación figurativa.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina, Uruguay y (al menos según el *Diccionario de americanismos*, también en Paraguay), ***sablazo*** está más cerca de la definición esperada. En el DA se define *sablazo* como "recorte de un presupuesto". En Argentina y Uruguay generalmente se usa la palabra para esto mismo o para el concepto más general de un recorte de fondos inconsulto, una nueva imposición o un despojo monetario cometido por el estado o por un privado con poder sobre otro.

Puedo citar unos cuantos ejemplos periodísticos:

- «Es un [sablazo](https://www.lanacion.com.ar/384967-hay-que-importar-instituciones) a los feudos políticos provinciales, que deberán salir a cobrar impuestos a parientes y amigos. Es también un sablazo a los grupos industriales protegidos, que han esquilmado durante medio siglo a los consumidores.» (*La Nación*, 31/03/2002)
- «Parte de esas obras serán financiadas por los propios municipios que acaban de sufrir un nuevo [sablazo](https://www.clarin.com/economia/baja-subsidios-extiende-municipios-bonaerenses_0_Hy2v1H-nP7g.html) sobre sus golpeadas arcas que no por anunciado es menos doloroso.» (*Clarín*, 03/08/2012, sobre un recorte de subsidios)
- «Una fuente cercana a una de las empresas dijo ayer a El Observador que el proyecto de ley de medios es un “[sablazo](https://www.elobservador.com.uy/nota/canales-privados-juegan-fuerte-contra-el-llamado-de-la-tv-digital-2013712210)” para su negocio.» (*El Observador*, 01/07/2013)
- «Ganancias: en el Gobierno dicen que están dispuestos a meterle “un [sablazo](https://www.clarin.com/politica/ganancias-gobierno-dispuestos-meterle-sablazo_0_B1O1VB2zl.html)” al juego» (*Clarín*, 30/11/2016, referido a extender un impuesto a las máquinas tragamonedas)
- «Y al suavizar la forma de pago del ajuste tarifario, el Gobierno mostró su mejor perfil peronista: el [sablazo](https://www.lanacion.com.ar/2127732-de-vido-querido-el-pueblo-esta-contigo) sigue siendo un sablazo, pero ahora parece más amable.» (*La Nación*, 21/04/2018)

Answer (score 0):

Un especialista en dar el sablazo fue La Fontaine a quien mantuvo, entre otros, Mme de La Sablière. Pura especulación, pero puede que se popularizara hacer un Sablière :)

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuestas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!